# hoe to applied example in Sentiment analysis using textblob and naive bayes

Tags: dataset, data-science, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes, textblob

Hi i am using amazon food dataset and my project about sentiment analysis i used TextBlob and naive Bayes models and after i get the accuracy for both

i wants t to applied each model in example like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sieyb.png)
this is the code for predicting in TextBlob
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW4jk.png)

and this for Naive Bayes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CFQT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about text-blob, However I've tried implementing basic sentiment analysis through Naive-Bayes in a python script

You can get an idea here - https://github.com/Shady2kOver/naive-bayers-sentiment-analysis